# How to change Opencart product tooltip language?

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

So here is my mouse hover tooltip. I would like to change the language. I've installed another language, but this does not change. Any suggestions on how to change it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change this text you will have to edit the following file:

catalog/language/english/english.php

Anyway if you want to change any other text, all of them are here:

catalog/language/english/

In case of you want to change the text that appeared in the "best seller" module you have to edit:
catalog/language/english/module/bestseller.php

In case of you want to change the text that appeared in the "latest" module you have to edit:
catalog/language/english/module/latest.php

Regards,